# How to send response_type from Spring boot oauth2 client application

Tags: types, response, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to enable Oauth2 sso for spring boot client application , oauth2 provider says response_type is mandatory field , but I could not able to find way to send the response_type application.properties files.

Can we send it from java configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I guess he wants you to set a request header which you can set using HttpHeaders and send them using RestTemplate

for eg:
    `HttpHeader httpHeader=new HttpHeader();`
    `httpHeader.add("request_type","value you wanna set");`

then add this to your HttpEntity and then send it using RestTemplate